# What are the different between VMCI socket, Berkeley Socket and winsock?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

What are the different between VMCI socket, Berkeley Socket and winsock? and when to use each one?

Answer (score 1):

Berkeley Sockets is the original TCP/IP API and is found in Unix-based operating systems.

Winsock is a source and binary API/ABI which was created to bring order out of the confusion of multi-vendor TCP/IP on Windows in the 1990s before Microsoft clued up. It is found on Windows.

VCMI is for communicating between VMWare hosts and guests, or between guests.